# Generating XYZ tiles using MBTiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, tiles, mbtiles, xyz-tiles

I'm trying to generate an offline image via Google Maps web layer using Genereate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles) and keep getting the following error (this has never happened before):

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 455, in processAlgorithm
self.generate(writer, parameters, context, feedback)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 316, in generate
for result in threadPool.map(self.renderSingleMetatile, metatiles_by_zoom[zoom]):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.6\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
yield fs.pop().result()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.6\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 438, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.6\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
raise self._exception
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.6\apps\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 230, in renderSingleMetatile
self.writer.write_tile(tile, tileImage)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 401, in write_tile
self._init_zoom_layer(tile.z)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 393, in _init_zoom_layer
self._execute_sqlite("UPDATE metadata SET value='{}' WHERE name='bounds'".format(bounds))
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 373, in _execute_sqlite
conn.execute(cmd)

sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Execution failed after 29.74 seconds"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried unchecking 'render' as answered in another thread but this hasn't solved it...

Comment: someone (or something) else is using your spatialite db - make them/it stop

Comment: @Donny, It's likely that a request (`UPDATE` call) is opened to the DB and the request has not finished or was not closed properly. This is likely due to threading (`threadPool.map()`). Not sure how to fix it unfortunately.

Comment: I've download QGIS 3.16 Hannover and run the process to completion without issue. Anyone have an idea what's changed in 3.22?